# Incorrect brace matching in Netbeans 8.2 with PHP

Tags: php, laravel, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm trying to use Netbeans 8.2 to develop a laravel application. I noticed that there are some inconsistencies on brace/parenthesis matching on certain situations. For example when I type the last brace in

```
Route::get('app/test', function() {)
```

and press `enter` I expect

```
Route::get('app/test', function() {

})
```

but I get

```
Route::get('app/test', function() {
    )
```

And when I type the same, but inserting a space between the brace and the parenthesis, like this

```
Route::get('app/test', function() { )
```

and when I put the cursor right after the brace and type `enter`, the result is

```
Route::get('app/test', function() {
    )
}
```

Note where both the ending brace and ending parenthesis are.

How can I get it to work? In eclipse it works like a charm.

Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse and NetBeans read your intentions differently, it doesn't mean that one is right and the other is wrong, it just means that you're used to one IDE and need time to adapt to a new one (or stick with Eclipse)

Comment: @apokryfos It IS wrong. If 

    Route::get('app/test', function() {
        )
    }

isn't wrong, i'm killing myself right now. Pay attention: ( () { ) }. Who in the hell would have THIS intention?

Answer (score 0):

Please try one of the nightlies, maybe it is already fixed. If not, please create a ticket here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS. If there is a ticket, someone will be aware of it :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.